# recovering of a list in sharepoint 2013

Tags: list

If we edit a list can it be recover? i see versioning setting is enable that can be one option. Please try to help me. The list contain many items.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a granular backup (export) of the list in Central Administration, you could easily restore (import) the list from Central Admin, whenever you need to.

[image]